# WEKA IBk wrong Results for EditDistance (Levenshtein distance) - JAVA

Tags: java, weka, knn

im very new to WEKA and tried today an IBk-Algorithmn to classfify strings to different classes by the distance function Levenshtein-Distance. However I'm getting very bad results. My inputs are always getting assigned the same class (Class b) which is not correct at all. Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong?

Currently my Code is very simple:

```
        CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
        loader.setSource(new File("current_path"));
        Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

        int numberAttributes = data.numAttributes();
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
        EditDistance newWeka = new EditDistance();

        IBk ibk = new IBk(1);
        ((IBk) ibk).getNearestNeighbourSearchAlgorithm().setDistanceFunction(newWeka); 
        ibk.setCrossValidate(false);
        ibk.setMeanSquared(false);
        ibk.buildClassifier(data);

        System.out.println(ibk);


        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
        eval.evaluateModel(ibk, data);
```

The result:

```
** KNN Demo  **

Correctly Classified Instances           4               50      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         4               50      %
Kappa statistic                          0     
Mean absolute error                      0.398 
Root mean squared error                  0.4449
Relative absolute error                 97.2913 %
Root relative squared error             99.5586 %
Total Number of Instances                8     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0,000    0,000    ?          0,000    ?          ?        0,500     0,375     Surname
                 1,000    1,000    0,500      1,000    0,667      ?        0,500     0,500     Firstname
                 0,000    0,000    ?          0,000    ?          ?        0,500     0,125     Job
Weighted Avg.    0,500    0,500    ?          0,500    ?          ?        0,500     0,406     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b c   <-- classified as
 0 3 0 | a = Surname
 0 4 0 | b = Firstname
 0 1 0 | c = Job
```

The File:

```
"Attribute","class"
"Wellbrock","Surname"
"Kohler","Surname"
"Sanger","Surname"
"Jan","Firstname"
"Anna","Firstname"
"Tim","Firstname"
"Schmidt","Firstname"
"Consultant","Job"
```

Much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my own. The Problem is that for JAVA API the Standard Search-Algorithmn seems to be Zero-R, which always classifys all attributes to the most existing class.

I added this line to my code now the result is as expected: 
ibk.setNearestNeighbourSearchAlgorithm(new LinearNNSearch());

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b c   <-- classified as
 3 0 0 | a = Surname
 0 4 0 | b = Firstname
 0 0 6 | c = Job
```